# Combine multiple forms into one -formidable forms

Tags: wordpress

I am using Formidable forms in wordpress.I have created three forms and want to merge  three forms, name is a common field in all three forms. Is there a way to combine multiple forms  into one? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Export the three forms as CSV files and combine them in Excel, then import the new CSV file into a new Formidable form with all required fields.